# swap indices of rank 2 tensor

Tags: tensors

I have a second order mixed tensor represented by a 2x2 matrix:

$$A_{i}\,^{j}=
       \begin{pmatrix}
        1 & 0 \\
        -1 & 1 \\
        \end{pmatrix}_{ij}
$$

And a metric tensor

$$g_{ij}=
       \begin{pmatrix}
        2 & 3 \\
        3 & 4 \\
        \end{pmatrix}_{ij}
$$

I'm trying to find the elements of $A^{i}_{\,j}$, but I'm not sure how this can be done.

I've tried $A^{i}_{\,j}=g^{i\ell}(g_{jk}A_{\ell}^{\,k})$ but I'm pretty sure this isn't the way to do this.

So, how might I calculate the elements of that tensor? I'm not even sure if $g_{ij}=g^{ij}$ is correct.

Comment: Hint: Your formula does not look bad, the Ricci calculus usually tells you what to do, basically, if all indices are in the right positions the formula is good. $g^{ij}$ should be the inverse of the metric tensor since you do not change a vector if you first raise its index and then lower it again.

Comment: @Luke contra-variant metric needs to be inverse? Oh. How did I miss that? Thanks :)

Comment: Try to combine the equations $x_i = g_{ij} x^j$ and $x^k = g^{kl} x_l$ and you will see it (note: I am not just to metrics that are not symmetric, so I hope I did not swap any indices).

Comment: @Luke I somehow got back to the same $A$ matrix... really confused now.

Answer (score 2):

Since the multiplication of matrices $C=[C_{ij}]$ and $D=[D_{ij}]$ is given by a law such as $$(CD)_{ij}=C_{is}D_{sj}$$ 
with $s$ summing and something like that for any other cases, then for your case
$$A^i{}_j=g^{il}(g_{jk}A_l{}^k)$$
you must rearrange as
$$A^i{}_j=g^{il}A_l{}^kg_{kj}$$
and conclude that, matricially, this is $G^{-1}AG$, since $g^{ij}$ are the entries of the matrix $G^{-1}$, where $G=[g_{ij}]$.